# constexpr makes members invisible

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, constexpr

Sorry for the undescriptive title.

I have a class in a C++14 codebase, let's call it `HugeClass`. `HugeClass` is a LiteralType, so it has at least one constexpr ctor:

```cpp
    class HugeClass {
        public:
        constexpr HugeClass() : member{0}
        {
        }

        // Over 9k LOC

        ...

        private:
        int member;
    };
```

All good. But not.
clang-tidy plus `-std=c++14` barks:
`member initializer 'member' does not name a non-static data member or base class`.

This doesn't happens with reordered fields:

```cpp
    class HugeClass {
        private:
        int member;

        public:

        ...
    };
```

nor it does with `-std=c++17`.
Removing constexpr weirdly works.

- What I'm doing wrong?
- Does the Standard touches this?
- Could it be a possible bug in clang(-tidy)?

Comment: I can't speak for tidy, but vanilla clang and g++ both accept this code.

Comment: I also [can't reproduce](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/v-qQLa). Can we get a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

C++14 §7.1.5 ("The constexpr specifier") lists a bunch of requirements for `constexpr` constructors. Neither of them contradicts you code. On the contrary, you can find your code as an example in this very section under (4.9):

```
struct Length {
  constexpr explicit Length(int i = 0) : val(i) { }
private:
  int val;
};
```